# MatLab help! Error using plot3 Not enough input arguments

Tags: matlab

```
fid =fopen(datafile.txt','r');  
data = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f');  
plot3(data(:,5),data(:,6),data(:,7))  
fclose(fid);
```

I am getting the error:

> Error using `plot3`
>   Not enough input arguments.

Where am I going wrong here? my data file is just columns of doubles (hence `%f`)

Comment: Did you check if `data` is actually fetching the correct information from the text file?

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those cases where the error isn't very informative. The problem here isn't that there aren't enough input arguments, it's that they are of the wrong type...

Your problem is that [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) actually returns the loaded data in a 1-by-N [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), where N is the number of columns (i.e. format specifiers, like `%f`) in your file. Each cell holds one column of data. You need to [extract the contents](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html#zmw57dd0e30216) of the cells using curly braces in order to pass it to `plot3`, like so:

```
plot3(data{5}, data{6}, data{7});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `data{5}, data{6}` and `data{7}`?  I believe the nested cell array contains individual cells where each cell represents a column of what you're looking for.  Also `data{:, 5}` would produce a comma-separated list so I'm not sure what it would produce when being called with `plot3`.

Comment: @rayryeng: Yes, it's clearer to write it as `data{5}`, but it should still work even as `data{:, 5}`, since the first dimension should be of size 1 (the default output from `textscan` is always 1-by-N, I believe).